# Is a hole better for creating a toroidal vortex than a pipe?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vortex

Does a hole work better for creating a toroidal vortex, where the fluid starts to turn as it exits, than a pipe, where the flow inside is more laminar. Some  high power vortex guns have a cone shaped barrel. So, is a cone better?

[image]

Comment: I think a hole may be better.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea why they use a cone on the high power ones?

Comment: The main reason behind using that cone shape is to make it more efficient.

Comment: There will be some dead gas left inside the circular one. It can be seen easily in liquids, the same holds here.

Comment: But this cannot occur in the cone shaped ones. Because the shape of the surface the area of gas travelling.

Comment: I found the image. It appears, you are referring to a cone tapering in, like a jet nozzle. The one I'm referring to tapers out.

Answer (score -1):

[enter link description here](http://www.bg.ic.ac.uk/research/k.parker/homepage/Mechanics%20of%20the%20Circulation/Chap_05/fig05-14.jpg)

Hope this image help you!!!

The thing here assume the pipe only one side, gas is moving similar to given image. 
If it is a cone then you can see that almost all the gas entering leaves out. Hence the power is also increased.

Comment: I wonder if the flow entering the cone goes up the middle and the sides of the cone create a long separation zone, peeling the sides of it away and rolling them into a toroid as it travels down.

Comment: On further research, I found this is indeed the case. There is a long separation zone down the sides of the cone, which peals fluid from the stream & rolls it into a torroid. Thank you, your image was the clue.